# Javascript code for identicon

Tags: javascript, identicon

I have tried to find a good javascript identicon generator but found none. Can anyone give me a link/ code of a good javascript identicon generator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identicon generation is about creating images so it has to be done on server side.
But it seems there is an [implementation in node.js](https://npmjs.org/package/identicon#readme)

EDIT: Oh, sorry, probably it could be done with canvas too. Examples: [1](http://francisshanahan.com/index.php/2010/html5-identicons-using-canvas-jquery-plugin/), [2](https://github.com/donpark/identicon/tree/master/identicon-canvas), [3](http://lesson8.blogspot.com/2013/02/a-jquery-plugin-html5-identicons-using.html)